# How are "<=" and "<" used in this code where there are more than two operands?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a course for coursera and came across the following code:

```
def is_selected(self, pos):
    inside_hor = self.location[0] <= pos[0] < self.location[0] + TILE_WIDTH
    inside_vert = self.location[1] - TILE_HEIGHT <= pos[1] <= self.location[1]
    return  inside_hor and inside_vert
```

I cannot understand how the `<=` and `<` are used. I know that they mean "smaller or equals" and "smaller than", but how am I to evaluate the value of `inside_hor`?

Why is `inside_hor = self.location[0] <= pos[0] < self.location[0] + TILE_WIDTH` written like that, what function do the `<=` and `<` serve here, is there an alternative way of writing it?

Comment: I guess `inside_hor` is supposed to become a `boolean` statement like True or False

Comment: `a <= b < c` means that 'b' is between 'a' and 'c' (b may be the same as a but smaller then c)